# Why does printing reference of a char type variable returns the value in it?

Tags: c++, reference

### Code Snippet :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c = 50;
    int i = 50;

    std::cout<<&c<<"\n";
    std::cout<<*(&c)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<&i<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

### Expected output :

```
<memory_address>
2
<memory_address>
```

### Original output :

```
2
2
0x7ffee0504ac4
```

### Confusion :

I thought `&` in this case should return the reference of the variable, printing which (according to me) should give me a memory address, which turns out to be true with variables of other data type like `int`,`float` and `double`

then why in the case of type `char`, it is displaying the value in it ?

---

**compiler =** clang-1103.0.32.62

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because of overload for `operator<< (const char*)` for ostream.

`&c` is of type `char*` and the `operator<<` tries to print 0-terminated C-string.
If you cast to void* as `(void *)(&c)` then you will get memory address as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c = 50;
    int i = 50;

    std::cout<<&c<<"\n";   // this will try to print null-terminated char* string.
    std::cout << (void*)(&c) << "\n"; // this will print memory address as expected
    std::cout<<*(&c)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<&i<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note: `cout << &c` may print some more characters, depending what bytes are present behind memory address `&c` ( the 0-byte could be far behind). So this is basically undefined behavior (UB).

Answer (score 2):

There are no references in your code. `&` is the *address-of* operator which returns a pointer not a reference. `&` only means reference when it's used in a declaration, not when it's used in an expression.

The reason you get different results for `&c` and `&i` is that `operator<<` has an overload for `char*` which assumes that the argument is a C string. Since that's not the case for you, your program actually has undefined behaviour.